# Tokenize a String

Tags: code-golf

Write a program or function that takes in a string through STDIN or function parameters, tokenizes it by parenthesis, and outputs the tokens on different lines.  If the string contains a parentheses error, the program/function must output a falsey value or error message.

#### Examples:

**Input:** `abc(def)ghi`

**Output:**

```
abc   ghi
   def
```

**Input:** `abc(def(ghi))jklm(n)op((q))rs`

**Output:**

```
abc      jklm op rs
   def       n
      ghi       q
```

**Input:** `blah(blah)(blah`

**Output:**

```
Error
```

#### Notes:

- The falsey value or error message must be generated by program, and the program must terminate successfully.  A built in error message due to a crash does not count.
- This is code golf. I will accept the shortest answer in bytes one month from today (July 30th).
- No standard loopholes.

Comment: There's no point putting something in the sandbox for 1 hour before you post it. Give it a couple of days so that people have time to see it and give feedback.

Comment: Will do next time

Answer (score 1):

## Cobra - 238

```cobra
def f(s='')
    x,y,l=0,0,for n in (r=s.count('('))get' '.repeat(s.length-2*r)
    try
        for c in s,branch c
            on c'(',y+=1
            on c')',y-=1
            else,l[y]=l[y][:x]+'[c]'+l[y][x+=1:]
        assert y==0
    catch
        print'Error'
    success,print l.join('\n')
```